# How can i access etherpad on local domain?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu

So i installed Etherpad-Lite on an (Ubuntu 20.04) VM on our server.
I also installed Nginx and set up the following vhost.
In my sites-available there are 2 entries: default and etherpad.conf
This is my **etherpad.conf**

```
upstream etherpad {
   server localhost:9001;
   keepalive 32;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name example.etherpad.at;

   location / {
       client_max_body_size 50M;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_pass http://etherpad;
   }
}
```

And this is my **settings.json** for Etherpad (ip set to 127.0.0.1)

```
   * IP and port which Etherpad should bind at.
   *
   * Binding to a Unix socket is also supported: just use an empty string for
   * the ip, and put the full path to the socket in the port parameter.
   *
   * EXAMPLE USING UNIX SOCKET:
   *    "ip": "",                             // <-- has to be an empty string
   *    "port" : "/somepath/etherpad.socket", // <-- path to a Unix socket
   */
  "ip": "127.0.0.1",
  "port": 9001,
```

I've also added a DNS entry in my host file and in my Firewall, just for testing purpose.

But when i go to the domain or the IP, i get an "This website is not reachable.....right dns...proxy...)
Ultimate when i set the ip of etherpad to something else i always get:
**Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL**

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently i had everything configured right but only after a reinstallation it worked.